# jquery animation for OnBegin and Success is interrupted and not smooth at all anymore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

Since I did a change : [Rewrite an asp.net mvc ajax actionlink as a jquery/ajax statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389740/rewrite-an-asp-net-mvc-ajax-actionlink-as-a-jquery-ajax-statement) 
the following code does not offer anymore a smooth fade in/out animation when I click one of those three links: Why is 
That ?

```
        function OnBeginStuff() {
            $("#StuffPanel").fadeTo("slow", 0.50);
        }
        function OnCompleteStuff() {
            $("#StuffPanel").fadeTo("slow", 1.00);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.mainLink', $('#NavigationPanel')).click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr('href'),
                    beforeSend: OnBeginStuff,
                    complete: OnCompleteStuff,
                    success: function (html) {
                        $('#StuffPanel').html(html);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="NavigationPanel">
        @Html.ActionLink("1", "Index", "One", null, new { @class = "mainLink" })
        @Html.ActionLink("2", "Index", "Two", null, new { @class = "mainLink"  })
        @Html.ActionLink("3", "Index", "Three", null, new { @class = "mainLink" })    
    </div>
    <div id="StuffPanel">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mario l switched from 3 ajax.actionlinks to 3 html.actionlinks and ajaxified them with jquery. Sorry all this is the correct link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389740/rewrite-an-asp-net-mvc-ajax-actionlink-as-a-jquery-ajax-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there any reason you are using both the `#NavigationPanel` and `.mainLink` for binnding the click function.
try this

```
$('.mainLink').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr('href'),
                    beforeSend: OnBeginStuff,
                    complete: OnCompleteStuff,
                    success: function (html) {
                        $('#StuffPanel').html(html);
                    }
                });
            });
```

or if you need to use both the selectors then add this line to the click event handler
`e.stopPropagation();` after `e.preventDefault();` this way bubbling of the events will be stopped and only single call to `ajax` and `OnBeginStuff` and `OnCompleteStuff` will be sent.

Comment: Sorry this morning my SSD crashed. Can only test your solution in next weekend. But afair i used your same code before and there were also the same animation problems.

Comment: ok back. The original problem seems gone. The fade animation is smooth again. But now I have a new problem lol... new post...thanks Parv.